# CSS layout: how to break the first column after N elements, and follow in the second column, just with CSS?

Tags: css, layout

The HTML code is fixed and I cannot change it:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Element 1</div>
  <div>Element 2</div>
  <div>Element 3</div>
  <div>Element 4</div>
  <div>Element 5</div>
  <div>Element 6</div>
  <div>Element 7</div>
</div>
```

I can only change the CSS

I want a two-columns layout, that way:

```
+-----------------------+ +-------------+
|       Element 1       | | Element N+1 |
+-----------------------+ +-------------+
+-----------------------+ +-------------+
|       Element 2       | | Element N+2 |
+-----------------------+ +-------------+
...
+-----------------------+ +-------------+
|       Element N       | | Element 2N  |
+-----------------------+ +-------------+
                          +-------------+
                          | Element 2N+1|
                          +-------------+
                          ...
                          +-------------+
                          | Element 2N+M|
                          +-------------+
```

I know how to select the first N elements and apply a different style (here: N=4):

```css
.wrapper > div:nth-child(-n+5) {
  width: 66vw
}
.wrapper > div {
  width: 33vw
}
```

What I miss is how to position the elements as in the diagram.

Comment: Look into grid to dispatch children into à column  or the other.

Comment: I started looking at grid and flex, indeed, and finally, a very simple solution is enough: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60773830/7351594. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well I could get the result with:

```css
.wrapper > div:nth-child(-n+5) {
  width: 66vw
  margin-left: 0;
  float: left;
}
.wrapper > div {
  width: 33vw;
  margin-left: 66vw;
}
```

Comment: Comment from https://talk.observablehq.com/t/fullscreen-layout-demo-notebook-is-broken/3142/6: "It can be quite tricky to flow elements across columns without additional wrappers. For what it’s worth: display:inline-block can often be easier to handle."

Answer (score 0):

**Using 2n+1 trick, adding clear both property we can break columns and get desired layout**

```css
.wrapper:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      clear: both;
    }

    .wrapper>div {
      float: left;
      width: 33vw
    }

    .wrapper>div:nth-child(2n+1) {
      clear: both;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div>Element 5</div>
    <div>Element 6</div>
    <div>Element 7</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not the layout I was looking for.

Comment: I finally could get the desired layout. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60773830/7351594